# Other way show that $\zeta(-2)=(-\frac{1}{12})\mod 2$?

Tags: congruences, riemann-zeta, research

> Lemma: We knew that for any  integer $a$ : ${a}^{p}=a \mod p$.

Then $1^p=1\mod p ,2^p=2\mod p ,3^p=3\mod p , \ \dots,\  n^p=n\mod p $.

Just to sum each term by term RHS and LHS we will get the following:

$1^p+2^p+3^p+ \dots + n^p= (1+2+3+ \dots +n)\mod p $.

let $ n$  go to $\infty$ we get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \mod p \tag{I}$$

let $p=2$ then if i'm right, the RHS of (I) =$-\frac{1}{12}$ according to Euler's proof and the LHS is $\zeta(-2)$. Hence we get:

$\zeta(-2)=-\frac{1}{12} \mod 2 $.

Is there someone show me a little bit if my proof to show that :$\zeta(-2)=-\frac{1}{12} \mod 2 $ is true, or does this make no sense?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: I'm sorry to say: make no sense.

Comment: ok, could you show me why ?

Comment: pleas show me where is the wrong in my steps ,

Comment: Since $12 \equiv 0 \mod 2$, how can we talk about $\frac{1}{12} \mod 2$?

Comment: @cbishop, if you belive that :1+2+3+..=-1/12 you can accept easly :1/12 mod2

Comment: It's not a matter of belief. It's not true that that sum is $-1/12$. It's just a lazy person's way of saying the $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you can advice me to be far for this lazy person

Comment: Since $\zeta(-2)=0$, your proof cannot be correct (making what I think is a reasonable assumption about what "mod 2" should mean for real or complex numbers).  You're absolutely right that the *partial* sums obey this rule: $1+2+...+n \equiv 1^p + 2^p + \ldots + n^p$ (mod $p$) for each natural number $n$ and prime $p$.  But since these partial sums don't converge to $\zeta(-p)$, you really can't say anything further.

Comment: @mjqxxxx12 , The problem is not in my proof , or zeta(-2) ,the problem how to believe that zeta(-1)=-1/12?

Comment: Further evidence that thid one numberphile video has polluted understanding of mathematical understanding more than clarifying it. I can't inform you about limits and series and whether you can conclude stuff modulo other stuff. That's too much time to spend on one question. @AniFier It's not your fault, somebody taught you something cool looking without explaining to you that it is nonsense.

Comment: Okay... since $1+2+3+\ldots \neq \zeta(-1)$ (as the left-hand side isn't even well-defined), starting with the divergent series to try to understand why $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$ is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: why is not defined ? i fixed p=2, and ,i think i can pass for summation to infty

Comment: and -1/12 almost equal 0, mayeb it will correct numerically

Comment: This question needs the attention of someone who is versed in $p$-adic $L$-functions.

Comment: @deoxygerbe Actually it does not (or maybe you were joking?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you buy the silly formulation: $1+2+3+\dots = -1/12$, you still can't say that $1+2+3+\dots\equiv 1^p+2^p+\dots$, because the finite proof of $a+b\equiv a^p+b^p$ doesn't apply to infinite sequences.

For example: $1+3+3^2+\dots = -\frac{1}{2}$ in "some sense." But:

$$1^2+3^2+3^4\dots =-\frac{1}{8}$$

Is $$-\frac{1}{2}\equiv -\frac{1}{8}\pmod {2}?$$

No, it is not, under any useful definition of that expression.

We know that if $a_i\equiv b_i\pmod p$ then for any $n$, $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\equiv b_1+b_2+\cdots b_n\pmod p,$$ but we can't conclude from those finite expressions that:

$$a_1+a_2+\cdots =b_1+b_2 +\cdots \pmod p$$

We prove the first by induction, but infinite sums cannot be reached by induction - you can't just wave you hands and say "In the limit, they must be congruent." By the same reasoning, in the limit, $1+2+3+\cdots$ must be positive.

Take the first step in the "proof" of $1+2+3+\cdots=-\frac1{12}$:

$$1-1+1-1+1\cdots = \frac{1}{2}$$

Multiply both sides by $2$, and we'd get:

$$2-2+2-2+\cdots = 1$$

Therefore $0\equiv 1\pmod 2$! Is that a useful way of looking at modular arithmetic?

Ultimately, you have to define stuff and prove stuff. Go back to your definitions.

The damage done by the nonsense $1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$ is not that it is wrong. It *is* wrong, technically, but if you rewrite it as $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$, it is true.

The damage is precisely the complete lack of definitions and proofs of what manipulations are allowed to "prove" this sort of sum. It gives novices the idea that they can play will infinite series willy-nilly without even the vaguest caution. *Anything* involving the infinite in mathematics requires care.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but :zeta(-2)=1²+2²+3²+........=0, does it meant that it's undefined ?

Comment: It's true that $\zeta(-2)=0$. That stuff about $1^2+2^2+\dots$ is just nonsense, and doesn't belong. @AniFier Anyway, what is "it" in your question? Is what undefined?

Comment: I think what i claimed to be true numerically if and only if Euler proof true

Comment: Or what i wrote are wrong complet

Comment: Again, you need to be specific. Do you really think you can proof that $(a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots)^p\equiv a_1^p+a_2^p+a_3^p+\dots\pmod p$? It's obviously *not* true.

Comment: I don't know, and what is a goal for proving it ?

Comment: I would definitely be inclined to say what you wrote is "wrong completely."

Comment: Ask specific questions. I'm stopping answering any questions with the word "it" in them, because you simply fail to communicate anything specific. You have to be clear or you won't be understood.

Comment: i don't claimed that :$(a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots)^p\equiv a_1^p+a_2^p+a_3^p+\dots\pmod p$

Comment: You most certainly did for the specific case of $a_i=i$, and you didn't give any argument for why. @AniFier

Comment: only i made sum term by term i got :$a_1^p+a_2^p+a_3^p+\dots\pmod p$

Comment: I used congruence of sum relation

Comment: Well, good luck. I recommend to (re)-take calculus, then take some complex analysis, and take some number theory, and then you might understand that nothing you have written makes any sense. As I say, you have been misled by a popularization of some mathematical nonsense that has a very **subtle** underlying truth, but which does not allow you to do these kinds of manipulations.

Comment: If $a\equiv b\pmod p$ and $c\equiv d\pmod p$ then $a+c\equiv b+d\pmod p$. That is not true for infinite sums. Infinite sums are not even defined, modulo $p$, except when all but finitely many of the values are $0\pmod p$.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for this

Comment: and I mad sums after applying it for finit sum .

Comment: I understand that am wrong to take this sum going to infty and i used sum congruence relation for finit sum .before

Answer (score 0):

There are several foggy steps...

- you add infinitely many numbers,
- you use $1+2+3+\dots=-\frac1{12}$, which I personally do kind of believe in, but it obviously cannot be rigolously valid,
- What does it mean to be congruent to $-\frac1{12}$ at all modulo $2$? Are we talking about only integers, or not?
- Note also that you are talking about the sum of sequence $1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$ (either as $n$ or $n^2$) modulo $2$.

The rest of logical arguing seems correct.

Comment: I mean the remain is :-1/12

Comment: yes, only about integer , but i based over Euler proof formula

Comment: So, e.g. $\frac{23}{12}\equiv-\frac1{12}\pmod2$?

Comment: 1+2+3+.....=-1/12 , how ? , is it wrong ?

Comment: **In what sense do you mean this infinite sum**? Obviously $1+2+3+\dots\ =\infty$, no?

Comment: just to get the zeta(-2) formula, should be sum to infty

Comment: Does Euler formula wrong ?

Comment: In a sense, yes, I would say, this formula is nonsense. The logic of our argument is basically correct. However, this is an interesting area.. Because.. there must be a context of numbers where they do behave like this.

Comment: sorry there are  several idea about zeta(-2) that we can't understanding it

Comment: ,if we accept Euler formula then zeta(-2) is not 0